# Error in upgrading php7.1 for pecl_http when restarting httpd service on Centos 7

Tags: apache, pecl, php-7.1

Anyone know how to resolve the below error for pecl_http.so?

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so: undefined symbol: uidna_IDNToASCII in Unknown on line 0`

Below are the packages installed.

```
    Package   Version State
    apcu      5.1.7   stable
    geoip     1.1.1   beta
    pecl_http 3.1.0   stable
    propro    2.0.1   stable
    raphf     2.0.0   stable
```

Below are the PHP Packages:

```
mod_php71w.x86_64                   7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-cli.x86_64                   7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-common.x86_64                7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-devel.x86_64                 7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-gd.x86_64                    7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-intl.x86_64                  7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-mbstring.x86_64              7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-mcrypt.x86_64                7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-mysql.x86_64                 7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-opcache.x86_64               7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-pdo.x86_64                   7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-pear.noarch                  1:1.10.1-1.w7                   @webtatic
php71w-pecl-apcu.x86_64             5.1.7-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-process.x86_64               7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-soap.x86_64                  7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
php71w-xml.x86_64                   7.1.3-1.w7                      @webtatic
webtatic-release.noarch             6-9                             installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone faces similar situation, there seems to be a bug on pecl_http-3.1.0 for Centos 7. I end up just using the previous stable version of pecl_http-3.0.1